# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InterstitialAdView", referenced from:

Tags: ios

I have created a framework &  integrated in the another app(Demo). When i run this Demo app on simulator then there is not any error...

But when do i run on device its gets error.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mac/Desktop/library file/Demo/pk.framework/pk, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/mac/Desktop/library file/Demo/pk.framework/pk
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InterstitialAdView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please share your experience.

I am using Xcode 9.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to know simulator and devices have different cpu types, when you build Xcode will build the app and link the libraries according to the target type.

From the error info, it seems your framework only provide the x86_64 architecture (for simulator), you should build your framework for the device architecture (arm64) instead !